# intent.getAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) and intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to launch different activities for screen on action and for incoming call. But the broadcast receiver shows error and crashes. Have no idea why such error crops up. My broadcast receiver is :

```
public class lockscreenBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Lockscreen.class);
            intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent2);
        }
        Log.i("TAG", ""+intent.getAction());
        String call_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(call_state.equals("RINGING") && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
        {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, Phone_call.class);
            intent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent3);
        }
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Lockscreen.class);
            intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
            context.startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
}
```

My service code is :

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service{
    BroadcastReceiver receive = new lockscreenBroadcast();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.i("TAG", "service");
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock k1;

         //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

         KeyguardManager km =(KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
         k1= km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
         k1.disableKeyguard();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        IntentFilter filter4 = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        registerReceiver(receive, filter);
        registerReceiver(receive, filter2);
        registerReceiver(receive, filter3);
        registerReceiver(receive, filter4);
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receive);
    }

}
```

And my error looks like this :

```
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast  Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x40000000 } in app.santanu.Service_and_Broadcast.lockscreenBroadcast@406a7c78
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at app.santanu.Service_and_Broadcast.lockscreenBroadcast.onReceive(lockscreenBroadcast.java:26)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
12-24 17:02:20.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     ... 9 more
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x40000000 } in app.santanu.Service_and_Broadcast.lockscreenBroadcast@406a7c78
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at app.santanu.Service_and_Broadcast.lockscreenBroadcast.onReceive(lockscreenBroadcast.java:26)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
12-24 17:02:20.309: E/AndroidRuntime(6693):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: what is line number `lockscreenBroadcast.java:26` ?

Comment: didn't get your question